# VS 2015 - Created solution folders are not appearing on file system

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, projects-and-solutions

I think this is a known problem with real folders and solution folders in visual studio. I'm facing now the same issue. I got a project handedover from other developer and he already created, directly under the solution some folders and sub folders. All these directories and sub directories are appearing in visual studio solution explorer and also on the file system. As I mentioned, I'm using VS 2015. Here a screenshot:

[image]

I have no idea how he did this or if he used any tool for that.
When I try to create a sub folder under SQL-Scripte folder and add some files to it, then the added files are appearing directly under the solution directory. See this screenshot:

[image]

Any help is highly appreciated :).
Thanks!

Comment: I guess he added folder in file system manually.

Comment: @qxg, i did this also, but they are not appearing in visual studio under the sql-scripte folder

Comment: are you telling us that "right click on folder SQL-Skripte -> Add -> new Folder" is not working for you?

Comment: @Pio, i guess my question is mentioning exactly what the problem is. I'm able to create the folders even with "right click -> Add -> new solution Folder" (not new Folder), but they are not reflecting on file system

Comment: If you create file in file system and cannot see in solution browser, then, In solution browser, you can show all the files and then include them in the project. There is button on top to show all the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the folders that you create as solution folders, are virtual ones that you cannot see on the file system. To be able to see the folders on both sides (VS and file system), I managed to fix this with the following work around:

1- Create a solution folder (let us name it newSql) under your SQL-Scripte folder

2- Add the files to it.

3- You will notice that the files are located directly under your solution folder in the file system. Exactly as you mentioned in the second screenshot.

4- Now close your visual studio and navigate to your solution directory.

5- Create under the folder SQL-Scripte (on file system), a folder named newSql and copy the files from your solution directory (in your case the SQL file that starts with 1.17....) to this newSql physical system folder.

6- Then open your (.sln) file with Notepad or Notepad++

7- Locate the entry for the new added newSql folder and there change the path to point to your new file system newSql folder. Like this: SQL-Scripte\newSql\1.17.sql

8- Save and again open VS. If you are using TFS then you should right click on the 1.17.sql file and click add to source control and check in.

Like this, you will see the folder on both sides and you can manage it only from VS.

Hope it helps.